# How to do pagination for three divs separately in the same page in cakephp?

Tags: cakephp, html, pagination

I have three divs (on the same page)with different id that I would like to use pagination for. I am using CakePHP's inbuilt pagination method to bring about this. The first page for all the divs are displayed correctly. But if I am in the first page of the second div and click the next link, I get the next items of the first div.

And similarly, If there are no items for the third div for the second page, yet I get the items for the first div.

How can I go about setting up pagination to control the three lists independently?

Answer (score 1):

There is a post about this on the [Debuggable](http://debuggable.com) site.

[How to have multiple paginated widgets on the same page with CakePHP](http://debuggable.com/posts/how-to-have-multiple-paginated-widgets-on-the-same-page-with-cakephp:48ad241e-b018-4532-a748-0ec74834cda3)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use inbuilt pagination, you won't be ale do this.
Thus, you have to write your own pagination. or just create new helper extends on the original one